# OSQL command to stop the services

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to stop the services using net stop and it is through database.
Connecting the database through OSQL and execute net stop command to stop the services.

Some service name having space so i need to enclose the service name with double quotes or otherwise each word in the service name considered as parameter instead of name.

If i use the double quotes then OSQL command is not working.

Please help me on this. Below is the sample query.

```
osql -U mpsappuser -P password -S %servername% -d DBName -Q "execute xp_cmdshell 'net STOP "MPS AS2 Service"'"
```

Comment: This command does *not* make sense. You open the *shell* to run an osql command that will execute an elevated *stored procedure* that will run  *a shell* command? Why don't you execute `net STOP "MPS AS2 Service"` directly? At least this way you won't end up disabling SQL Server's security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Query will work

```
osql -U mpsappuser -P password -S %servername% -d DBname -Q "DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(100) SELECT @CMD = 'net STOP ' + CHAR(34) + 'MPS AS2 Service' + CHAR(34) + '' execute xp_cmdshell @CMD"
```